# Edge softening with cycles material

Tags: rendering

Is there an edge softening option for rendering? I don't have the time to model a high poly model and I want these soft edges only for renderbut not in the geometry. This possible in rhino 6 render and vray already; is it also possible in blender?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

Cycles has a *Bevel* node (found in the add menu under *Input>Bevel*) that does exactly what you want. Simply plug the output of the *Bevel* node into the normal input on your shader/material and that's it. The example below shows a basic setup. The radius can be increased to make the corners look even more rounded.

[image]

Blender also has a *Bevel* modifier that will add the geometry very quickly as well. Depending on your model it may be an option too.